# How do I configure Hot Chocolate GraphQL enum to return the Enum description

Tags: .net, graphql, hotchocolate

Can HotChocolate GraphQL be configured to convert all enums to their description attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The code below does the trick however I released
what I was trying to do wasnt correct.
The enum description for NA was 'N/A', 'N/A' isnt a valid enum so HotChocolate throws an Exception

What I should be doing is creating extra fields for the enum descriptions

```
.AddConvention<INamingConventions, NamingConventions>();
```

```
    public class NamingConventions : DefaultNamingConventions
    {
        public override NameString GetEnumValueName(object value)
        {
            var type = value.GetType();

            var memberInfo = type.GetMember(value.ToString());

            var descAttribute = memberInfo?.FirstOrDefault()?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                ?.FirstOrDefault();

            return descAttribute == null
                ? value.ToString()
                : ((DescriptionAttribute)descAttribute).Description;
        }
    }
```